# eclipse rcp : about dialog contribution

Tags: eclipse-rcp

How can I let my plugin icon appear at here :[image]
Another question : how to write **about text** with format like above picture? As you can see, there are hyperlinks and line breaks, but in the product configuration only plain text is allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a branding plugin.  Here is [a tutorial](http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/09/branding-an-eclipse-plugin/) that shows the process.  In the feature.xml you can specify a branding plugin and in your branding plugin you can add about.ini and about.properties to add a feature image.  To modify the text in the about dialog itself you have to [define an Eclipse product](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_create_an_Eclipse_product?).